# Splitting comma separated flat file and reading the data row by row using Java transformation

Tags: informatica

I have a source flat file with comma separated, I am reading it as one long string with 1000 precision and then I want to use Java transformation and split them with column names which are spread across multiple header, and associate them with the values underneath. One input row will land as many target rows.

first thing:Read file line by line into a long string port.

Add "CurrentlyProcessedFileName" port to the source to capture the filename.
Count the number of rows read

Split the row on commas-- how do I implement this ?? guessing expression or java transformation and the below whole process  in java or can I use SP , bu how do I split the row on commas??

```
   If Current RowNumber = 1 Then    
        vINVC_BGN_DT := field1
        vINVC_END_DT := field2

   If Current RowNumber > 1
      If field1 != $$CARRIER Then
    NAME1 := NAME1 || field1  #Initialize NAME variables to an empty string
    NAME2 := NAME2 || field2
    NAME3 := NAME3 || field3  #repeat for each comma seperated field
      If field1 = $$CARRIER Then
    VALUE1 := field1
    VALUE2 := field2
    VALUE3 := field3          #repeat for each comma seperated field
```

For each source row, the number of output rows should equal the count of distinct Amount_types, (excluding empty ones)

```
   For i in NAME4.NAMEx loop
       if NAMEi is not spaces or null then generate row
           target.INVC_TYPE = "CLAIM"
           target.FILE_RECEIPT_SK
           target.CARRIER := VALUE1
           target.CNTRCT := VALUE2
           target.PBM_GROUP := VALUE3
           target.INVC_BGN_DT := vINVC_BGN_DT  #From row1
           target.INVC_END_DT := vINVC_END_DT  #From row1
           target.INVC_AMOUNT_TYPE := NAMEi
           target.INVC_AMOUNT := VALUEi
   end i loop..
```

Comment: How does your source file look like? What is $$CARRIER?

Comment: Please do not get into the habit of asking for urgency here - your question has exactly the same priority as the other hundreds of questions that have been asked today.

Comment: samik, my source  is a flat file which has a header as date start and end date , next line has field names which are about three lines and then the data all these are in one single string.